# How to save NSMutableArray to parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` called `thePlaylist`, it's contain list of `MPMediaCollection`. I tried to save it to parse but the column keep `empty(undefined)`, and the type of the column on parse is Array. How can I do it properly?

here is my code:

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()

var thePlaylistData: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(thePlaylist)

user?.setObject(thePlaylistData, forKey: "userPlaylist")
```

any comment or advice would be great.

Comment: can you post 'thePlaylist' data?

Comment: thePlaylist is an NSMutableArray, it's like {"MPMediaItemCollection <87asdf98>","MPMediaItemCollection <asd89f89>"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From Parse Documentation:](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects)

> We do not recommend storing large pieces of binary data like images or
>   documents using NSData fields on PFObject. PFObjects should not exceed
>   128 kilobytes in size. To store more, we recommend you use PFFile. See
>   the guide section for more details.

You can use PFFile:

```
 var thePlaylistData: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(thePlaylist)
 var music= PFObject(className:"Music")
 music["userPlaylist"] = thePlaylistData
 jobApplication.saveInBackground()
```

Comment: do you mean using PFFile on column type?

Comment: Parse do not accept more than 128kb in the table, your array is very likely to have more so you need to save in a file with a link to the db

Comment: Save the file in Parse db with a unique name like timestamp+username etc and save the file name in the specific row/column